# Is there a way to change the path of a function in the stack trace?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, runtime-error, stack-trace

Let's assume we have a function, which generates an error throwing function:

```
function p(){
    function q(){
        throw new Error();
    }
    q();
}
p();
```

The stack trace will look something like this:

```
Error: x
    at path:3:8
    at q (path:5:4)
    at p (path:7:1)
```

then the `p` function will look something like this:

How to change `p` to get a stack trace like the following?

```
Error: x
    at something-else:12:12
    at q (something-else:34:34)
    at p (path:7:1)
```

I don't control the files, because by client side code we use bundles nowadays, so putting `q` into a separate file is not a solution. As far as I know what I am asking is not possible, but maybe somebody knows more about js than I do. :D

If you are wondering what's the goal here, I'd like to teach the stack parser where the path is in a frame string.

Comment: Other than extending `Error` with a custom class that defines its own stack trace, I can't really think of anything else for client-side.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I was thinking on data URIs, but I cannot test it now and they don't work in old browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found multiple approaches:

#### 1.) data URI

I started with a data URI approach, which is not broadly supported, but still more than nothing:

```
function report(e){
    console.log(e.stack);
}

window.onload = function (){
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.setAttribute("src", "data:text/html,try {throw new Error;}catch(e){report(e);}");
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(s);
}
```

It works in recent major desktop browsers except IE, which does not allow data URI by script tags. It logs the following stack:

```
Error
    at data:text/html,try {throw new Error;}catch(e){report(e);}:1:12
```

#### 2.) IFrames

After that I thought about it and I had the idea that if this works with data URIs, then it will probably work with iframes as well, so I came up with this:

```
function report(e){
    console.log(e.stack);
}

window.onload = function (){
    var i = document.createElement("iframe");
    i.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(i);

    var idoc = i.contentDocument || i.contentWindow.document;
    var ibody = idoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.innerHTML="try {throw new Error;}catch(e){parent.report(e);}";
    ibody.appendChild(s);
}
```

It logs the following stacks:

FF:

```
@about:blank:1:12
window.onload@file:///C:/Users/inf3rno/Downloads/x.html:18:2
```

Chrome and Opera:

```
Error
    at <anonymous>:1:12
```

IE11

```
Error
   at Global code (Unknown script code:1:6)
   at window.onload (file:///C:/Users/inf3rno/Downloads/x.html:17:2)
```

We can add another frame simply by adding a function call:

```
s.innerHTML="function a(){\ntry {\nthrow new Error;\n}catch(e){\nparent.report(e);\n}\n};\n a();";
```

which logs the following in IE:

```
Error
   at a (Unknown script code:3:1)
   at Global code (Unknown script code:8:2)
   at window.onload (file:///C:/Users/inf3rno/Downloads/x.html:19:2)
```

So we can compare `at a (Unknown script code:3:1)` with a similar function called in the parent window: `at a (file:///C:/Users/inf3rno/Downloads/x.html:13:1)` and it is relative easy to find the path.

#### 3.) Eval

Using eval is an interesting approach. It gives something like `at a (eval code:3:1)` in IE, while in other browsers and node it gives a complicated nested location: `at a (eval at window.onload (x.html:21), <anonymous>:3:7)` or `at a (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:1), <anonymous>:1:20)`. I think this is the best approach, because it does not require DOM and it is available in every js environment even in strict mode.